# Lazy load components in NextJS without using `next/dynamic`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm creating a **component (Editor)  that needs to be lazy-loaded** always. But it needs to work in any React app.

`React.lazy` works with CRA but, not with NextJS and Gatsby and other SSG/SSR solutions.

I cant use `next/dynamic` cuz then my component gets tied to NextJS. And I'm trying to avoid using `react-loadable` to keep bundle size small for the user when the component is not needed.

I've tried lazy loading the following ways -

```js
const Title = () => <h1>title</h1>; // test component to lazy load
```

```js
const Title = React.lazy(() => import("./Title"));
const Method1 = () => <Title />;
```

```js
const Method2 = () => {
  const [Title, setTitle] = React.useState(React.Fragment);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    import("./Title").then((module) => setTitle(module.default));
  }, []);
  return <Title />;
};
```

```js
const Method3 = () => {
  const [Title, setTitle] = React.useState(React.Fragment);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTitle(require("./Title"));
  }, []);

  return <Title />;
};
```

```js
const Method4 = () => {
  const Title = React.createRef(React.Fragment);
  const [isClient, setIsClient] = React.useState(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    Title.current = require("./Title");
    setIsClient(true);
  }, [Title]);

  const Component = Title.current;
  return isClient ? <Component /> : null;
};
```

```js
// Next JS `page/index.js`
export default function IndexPage() {
  return <Method4 />; //<Method1 />, <Method2 />, <Method3 /> doesn't work either.
}
```

Codesandbox with code - https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-benz-emw2l?file=/pages/index.js:31-278

Comment: Have you tried using `loadable-components`? I think `next/dynamic` use it internally

Comment: @AndrewZheng Not that but I tried `react-loadable` which works, but I'm trying to avoid adding external packages, if possible so that when the editor is not needed, there's minimum impact on the user's bundle size.

Comment: both `react-loadable` and `loadable-components` are around 2KB gzipped + minified. So it really won't be the performance bottleneck in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the component to be rendered in the client-side only, by using the "use client" directive, but it's a new feature of NextJS 13.